# Paths to optimal K for GAM model selection

Tags: predictive-models, model-selection, aic, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

Let's say I have 10 different model combinations to compare via AIC for one year. There are 3 years of data, roughly 200-400 observations each year. For covariates, 2-3 of 5 appear to require tweaking via gam.check() more often than not--one year is particularly noisy. I am using gam.check() and ML to compare models with AIC. Using gam.check() is time intensive, one could easily fit custom K values for each model for all 10 different model combinations for one year. And so the same for the next year and next year. Maybe this time intensive option is actually done more often than I think. Goal of models is to show trends and relationships within a year and then across years, so covariates of least and most significance is of interest. Model fitting not centered on predictions but could be the case down the road.

I see that a fixed low K value has been set by others to show general ecological trends or to use default settings K=10 or K=-1. I see that a REML approach is preferred under fitting via GCV, and that a double penalty via select=TRUE is an option.

1. Should one covariate have the same K value for all 10 models within a year to compare via AIC?
2. Could one fit the most complex model for that year and use the resulting best fit K values from the complex model for the other less complex models for that year?
3. How to best select K value for the same covariate across different model combinations for the same data in one year?

Thank you kindly for any advice.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain your larger goal with this modelling, because I'm struggling to see why you'd be fitting separate models for each `year` and why you have 10 different models for each year. As your aim is to show "trends ... across years", modelling all years in a single model would seem prudent. Also, if "[m]odel fitting not centered on predictions...", your use of AIC for all of this is questionable; AIC is focused on prediction error

Comment: @GavinSimpson thank you! Years will all be combined into one model, actually, and run as factor for 25 years/random effect. My understanding is that if default k=10 is used for all covariates, year as a covariate but as a factor, should be assigned a k equal to the numbers of years in the data even though other covariates are assigned k=10. This would be k=25 for 25 years of data. Is this right, or can k for years be 10 as well? There may be predictions in the future.